# Access server bound to localhost:5000 from different computer

Tags: ssh, putty, tunnel

I am working on a web application using the Pylons framework. The web server is binding to localhost:5000 so I am able to access my application by going to localhost:5000 in my browser.

I would like to be able to access the server from another computer on the same network. The computer that is hosting the server and application is running Mac OSX and the computer I would like to be able to access the application is running Windows 7 (I have cygwin with SSH installed as well as PuTTY).

I could work around this by binding to the host name of the computer but would rather leave it running only on localhost. I was thinking I could do something with SSH tunneling but have not had any luck so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have puTTY, then open up an ssh connection to the Mac. Before actually clicking "Open", Go to Connection -> SSH -> Tunnels and add a tunnel:

Source port 5000

Destination localhost:5000

Type Local (default)

Now click "Open" and log in normally with user/pass. Now from your windows computer, you can access your appliation at localhost:5000 ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -L 5000:localhost:5000 ...
```